# Grails order of function execution

Tags: javascript, jquery, grails

I have a `formRemote` that calls a function in my controller when it is submitted like this:

```
<g:formRemote name="editIndivRecForm" url="[controller: 'customer', action:'saveEditedIndividualRecord']" onSuccess="doResult();">
```

This form is submitted by clicking on a button. Rather, a button that is clicked called `'save'` will do other things among clicking the form's submit button via Javascript. Here is the click handler for this button:

```
$('#save').click(function () {
            $("#uniqueId").prop('disabled', false); // Have to enable before form submission else it doesn't go back as a param to controller.
            $("#secondaryId").prop('disabled', false);
            $("#submit").trigger("click"); // formRemote's submit button
            $('#editIndivRecForm').reset;
            <g:remoteFunction controller="customer" 
                                        action="remediationSearch" 
                                        update="content_area" 
                                        params="{rerender: true}"/>
        });
```

The problem I'm running into is that I need the function of my controller called by the click handler `remediationSearch` to run AFTER the function of the controller called by the formRemote's submission `saveEditedIndividualRecord` is done executing. But it is happening the other way around. And for some reason the function `onSuccess="doResult();"` doesn't even execute otherwise I was going to move the following code into its body to make things work the way I want:

```
<g:remoteFunction controller="customer" 
                                            action="remediationSearch" 
                                            update="content_area" 
                                            params="{rerender: true}"/>
```

here is how `doResult` is now:

```
function doResult() {
            console.log("done.");
        }
```

the formRemote is submitted but the `doResult` function prints nothing to the console.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as all of the Grails AJAX related tags [have been deprecated](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/formRemote.html), I would recommend trying it this way:

Markup:

```
<form id="editIndivRecForm" onsubmit="return false;">
  <!-- add fields here -->
  <input type="text" id="uniqueId" value="${something}">
  <input type="text" id="secondaryId" value="${something}">
  <button id="save" type="button">
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
// Function to update your content_area div
function updateContentArea() {
    var params = { rerender: true };
    var url = "${createLink(controller: 'customer', action: 'remediationSearch')}";
    $.get(url, params, function(data) { 
        $("#content_area").empty().append(data); 
    });
}

$("#save").on('click', function() {
    // Collect values from form and submit ajax request
    // Using name and description for example fields here:
    var data = {
        name: $("#name").val(),
        description: $("#description").val(),
        uniqueId: $("#uniqueId").val(),
        secondaryId: $("#secondaryId").val()
    };
    var url = "${createLink(controller: 'customer', action: 'saveEditedIndividualRecord')}";

    // Submit the (first) AJAX request
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: url,
        data: data,
        success: function() {
            doResult();
            $('#editIndivRecForm').reset();
            updateContentArea();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: @caseyscarborough My project requires me to stick with Grails 2.3.8 for now. I there anyway you can show a solution that involves using the formRemote since I am allowed to use it?

Comment: @caseyscarborough Ok solved it, I wasn't returning any data from my controller so OnSuccess was never happening.

Comment: Glad you solved it! I never really use those tags, so I couldn't have come up with a solution using them quickly.